# regular expression in Eclipse search

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I need search some words in Eclipse wokspace. It should be exaclty matching that word.
 I need to search `'AT'` in eclipse workspace. But when I use eclipse search for AT it gives all the results which includes AT in any word which I dont want. Later I realised that I can use regular expression in Eclipse search for matching the exact word. For that I used the following regular expression. But It does not give any result.

```
\bAT\b
```

For example : I need to Search AT. It gives the result CAT as well. I need to get the result only AT.

```
public static final String AT = "AT" ;
```

The search result gives AT,CAT,ATA,etc.. But I dont need all these results. I need only `AT`

Comment: Can you give example of what you are actually looking for? If it is ' AT ' (with spaces around) then just do a normal search and add the spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following regular expression after restarting Eclipse:

```
\bAT\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Got to Search -> Search ... or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the *extended* search dialog.
There change the tab to File Search and on the right hand side check the Regular Expression checkbox.

After doing so you're able to search your **whole** workspace with your regex (`\bAT\b` worked just fine for me).

Hope this helps. Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

Browse to your workspace through file explorer . Open all source code in notepad++ . 
Ctrl+F . Tick regular expression in search dialog of notepad++ . Enter your regex and hit find in all open files .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what tou exactly search, you can use the following regexp :

```
[\s"^]AT[\s"$]
```

It should match :

- "AT"
- or [space]AT[space]
- or a line containing only AT